# Splitting PDF with PyPDF2 in Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pdf, aws-lambda, pypdf

I'm probably doing something really stupid here but I've got the following Lambda function to split an uploaded PDF into individual pages. When I upload an 8-page PDF, it creates 8 identical copies of the original PDF.

I must be doing something stupid but am not sure what.. Help!

```
import boto3
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Retrieve the uploaded file details from the event
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    file_name = file_key.split('/')[-1]  # Extract the original file name

    # Prepare the output directory path
    output_dir = 'PCP/temp/'  # Specify your desired output directory
    output_prefix = file_name.split('.')[0] + '-'  # Prefix for split file names

    # Download the uploaded file to temp storage
    temp_file_path = '/tmp/' + file_name
    s3.download_file(bucket_name, file_key, temp_file_path)

    # Read the uploaded PDF file
    pdf = PdfReader(temp_file_path)

    # Split the PDF into individual pages and save them
    for page_number in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        print (f"Page {page_number}")
        temp_output_path = f"/tmp/{output_prefix}{page_number + 1}.pdf"
        output_page_path = f"{output_dir}{output_prefix}{page_number + 1}.pdf"
        output_pdf = PdfWriter()
        output_pdf.add_page(pdf.pages[page_number])

        with open(temp_output_path, 'wb') as output_file:
            output_pdf.write(output_file)
        
        # Upload the split page to S3 bucket
        s3.upload_file(temp_file_path, bucket_name, output_page_path)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'PDF splitting completed successfully.'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `s3.upload_file` you are passing `temp_file_path` which references the original downloaded file rather than `temp_output_path` which is where you wrote the current page within the `for` loop.

I recommend using more descriptive variable names to help avoid such issues that are easy to miss with similar, generic variable names. Consider re-naming `temp_file_path` to `downloaded_pdf_path` and `temp_output_path` to `current_page_path`.

Comment: Hah, I *knew* I was being an idiot.. I've always used perl and am just picking up python so did a lazy copy and paste from something online and did a quick fiddle - I'd give it better variable names if I'd bothered to write from scratch. Fanx.